# How to unzip .app.zip file on mac os in python?

Tags: python, macos

Tried to use:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(bin_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
   zip_ref.extractall(temp_dir)
```

but, the code above extracts .app also to separate files.

Comment: how about using `extract` instead of `extractall` and specifying the exact file instead?

Comment: did not help. zip_ref already contains extracted files in filelist

Answer (score 0):

Try this methord

```
zip = ZipFile('file.zip')
zip.extractall()
```

Note - you need Python 2.6+ for this one

Comment: Unfortunately did not help